# Where can I store private key as environment variable in Mule?

Tags: mule, environment-variables

We are going to encrypt Mule servers and we need to store the private key for the same as environment variable. Where it should be stored ; in wrapper or in mule-conf xml OR could there be any other way to store the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what goal you have in mind - keep it secret/not readable, have it common for environment, have it common in cluster, share between projects/applications, have ability to modify, etc.

The most obvious and simplest way is to keep it in mule-project.xml.
[image]

Most important is the question - from whom it should be secret and not readable? You can store it(secret) in file which is readable only by particular user ID, so nobody (except root) can read it. You can store it in system environment variable. You can change it a little on the fly so nobody (even root) knows real value. However it will be in the application anyway (just before you submit it to encryption algorithm) and you don't trust your own application it will have this secret anyway. Determine whom you not trust and block them. But you cannot block absolutely everybody.

Most likely you want to prevent one environment (like DEV) to know secret for another environment (like PROD). Then store it is system environment variable and developers will not know it for PROD. Afraid that PROD root will use this secret by itself? Modify secret inside program (like add extra word) and root could not figure it out. But if developer who knows this approach tells root how to modify secret or vive versa root tells developer what is the system variable then we are back to stage where you cannot keep secret from absolutely everybody.

Comment: What if I want to make it secret/not readable then how should I proceed?